# Kibana visualize. Visualize URL, but group same path

Tags: kibana

Kind of hard to explain, but I will try.

I have some endpoints, with some paths.
I am measuring the time for each endpoint.

I want to visualize this in Kibana.

My problem is the following. The paths are not completely fixed. I have some path variables.
For example:

- /this/path/{something}
- /another/path/here/{somethingElse}

I am not interested in the specific calls. I want to group them before visualizing.
I want to know the average measured time for each path.

- /this/path/*
- /another/path/here/*

Is this possible with the visualization tool in Kibana?